# How to active next & prev controls on Android Mediacontroller?

Tags: java, android

I want to activate next and previous controls on Android Media controller in an android app.
I tried hard but still not achieve. How can i activate that controls? Any help will be appreciated.Code is:
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setPrevNextListeners(null, null);
    vv.setMediaController(mc);

Where vv is object created.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not setting a listener in `mc.setPrevNextListeners(null, null);`?

Comment: No there is no any reason but how should i set a listener in mc.setPrevNextListener(null,null)?

Comment: Dan Can you provide me some code about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using an [anonymous class or inner class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) will do the trick;

```
  mc.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
        // v is mc
        // code for next
     }
  }, new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
        // v is mc
        // code for previous
     }
  });
```

Comment: Dan one onClick is for next and other for prev?